# Can I define an ES6 static method from an imported object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-next

If I define some class:

```
class MyClass {
  static  myVar = { someKey: someVal };
...
}
```

but instead of defining the static variable from within the class, I want to import it from another file:

```
// utils.js
export const someObject = { someKey: someVal };
...
```

Will this work?:

```
import { someObject } from './utils.js';

class MyClass {
  static  myVar = someObject;
...
}
```

**edit:** The title to this question would more accurately be: "Can I define an ES6 static **field** from an imported object?" Static fields are currently a stage-2 proposal for JS. See @T.J.Crowder's answer below. and require the "babel-preset-stage-2" transpiler.

Comment: That's not a static method, it's a static field (which isn't standard yet).

Comment: Your original code that you're trying to emulate but with imported data doesn't even work.

Comment: @clockwork: Why not? (Provided they're using a transpiler for the static field syntax, of course, but that's true for the first code block as well...)

Comment: Yep, we use the babel-preset-stage-2 transpiler

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: No mention of a transpiler of or using early stage features. @ Drew: So your actual question is why the transpiler works for the first but not the second? I don't see that in the question and it works for me.

Comment: @clockwork: This syntax is so common (particularly in React circles) that it's not unreasonable to assume transpiling (as turned out to be the case). Drew2 didn't say it didn't work, he *asked* if it would work. (I'm assuming he tried it and it ran, but wanted to be sure that it wasn't dodgy in some way... :-) But it would have been good to include that -- and transpiling -- in the question. )

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: accurate, this is in the context of React. I will make note of the transpiler in the original question. And question is really a small piece of a whole as I begin to grapple with classes, subclasses, and how they work with JS's prototype-based inheritance.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Then the "no" answer provided would be even more odd if the OP tried it and found it worked. As would his referencing [ES6 documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static) if the OP knew it was an early stage feature. Nothing fits.

Comment: @clockwork: Question poster on SO uses slightly-incorrect terminology while posting without fully-complete information -- news at 11. ;-) *(Thanks, btw -- I **completely** missed that the "no" answer was from the OP!)*

Comment: @clockwork I had not tried this out in isolation, only in a broken branch of an app with a whole bunch of errors, and thought I had found the answer to my own question online. Thank you for challenging.

Comment: *"I had not tried this out in isolation"* In all honesty, that was my suspicion. Testing the code example is an important step before asking. It's never a wasted effort. @T.J.Crowder: lol, yeah, I know. I just like to cut through it all sometimes. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a static method, it's a static *field* (which isn't standard yet; [static fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-static-class-features/) are currently at Stage 2, although it's common to transpile the syntax as the *basics* of it seem unlikely to change).

But provided the semantics when static fields *are* standardized are as they currently stand (and it would be weird if they weren't), yes, you can do that. The initializer of a field can be any expression, including one that uses an imported binding.

---

If you want to do it now, without transpiling or waiting for static fields to become standard, just do the assignment afterward:

```
import { someObject } from './utils.js';

class MyClass {
  // ...
}
MyClass.myVar = someObject;
```

Comment: thanks for referencing the static fields proposal. When I initially wrote this question I titled it "Can I define an ES6 static variable (or method) from an imported variable (or method)?", but revised because I couldn't find anything on static variables.

Comment: @Drew2: No worries. Not sure why the question would have been downvoted, this stuff is new and the ways they can be combined aren't always obvious... :-)

Comment: in what order does the static field assignment happen? When the class is initialized with "new", the static assignment has already happened, right? The import occurs before the class constructor is defined?

Comment: @Drew2: The import occurs when your module is loaded, and is resolved before your `class` declaration is processed. The static field initializer is executed when the `class` declaration is processed (in source code order relative to others, if any), and so -- by definition -- before any calls to the constructor can be made. In the workaround at the end of the answer, since we do it as the first thing after the class declaration, there's similarly no opening for the constructor to be called. (There are differences in regard the scope the initializer sees, but nothing you need to worry about.)